# Expression must have arithmetic type

Tags: c, pointers, visual-studio-2015

While trying to write a code to find the intersection of two arrays,I came across a problem. I can't seem to modify a pointer inside a function.
Inside my find_intersection I get the error while doing the realloc function,compiler states that "counter" has no arithmetic value.
Any explanation on what went wrong here?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int quick_sort(int*, int, int);
void swap(int*, int*);
int partition(int *, int, int);
int input_array_dyn(int*n);
int *find_intersection(int*, int*, int*, int, int,int *);

main()
{
int size1, size2, *counter, i=0;
int *arr1 = input_array_dyn(&size1);
int *arr2 = input_array_dyn(&size2);

quick_sort(arr1, 0, size1 - 1);
quick_sort(arr2, 0, size2 - 1);

int *arr3 = (int*)calloc(size2, sizeof(int));
arr3= find_intersection(arr1, arr2, arr3, size1, size2, &counter);

printf("The size of the new array is:%d\n", counter);
while (i < counter)
{
    printf("%d\n", arr3[i]);
    i++;
}
free(arr1);
free(arr2);
free(arr3);
}

int *find_intersection(int *arr1, int *arr2, int *arr3, int SA, int SB, int *counter)
{
int i = 0, j = 0, n = 0;
*counter = 0;

while (i < SA &&j < SB)
{
    if (arr1[i] < arr2[j])
        i++;
    else if (arr2[j] < arr1[i])
        j++;
    else
    {
        arr3[n] = arr1[i];
        i++;
        n++;
        j++;
    }
}
counter = n;
arr3 = (int*)realloc(arr3, counter*sizeof(int));/*error here*/

return arr3;
}

int input_array_dyn(int*n)
{
int i;
int *a;
printf("Enter the size of the array:\n");
scanf("%d", n);
a = (int*)calloc(*n, sizeof(double));
assert(a);
printf("Enter the array elements:%d.\n", *n);
for (i = 0; i < *n; i++)
    scanf("%d", a + i);
return a;
}
void swap(int* a, int* b)
{
int t = *a;
*a = *b;
*b = t;
}
int partition(int *arr, int low, int high)
{
int pivot = arr[high];
int i = (low - 1);

for (int j = low; j <= high - 1; j++)
{
    if (arr[j] <= pivot)
    {
        i++;
        swap(&arr[i], &arr[j]);
    }
}
swap(&arr[i + 1], &arr[high]);
return (i + 1);
}

int quick_sort(int *arr, int low, int high)
{
if (low < high)
{
    int pi = partition(arr, low, high);

    quick_sort(arr, low, pi - 1);
    quick_sort(arr, pi + 1, high);
}
}
```

Comment: Do not describe error, quote it full and verbatim.

Comment: Also identify the line the error refers to, by adding a comment.

Comment: I do not really believe "i've left only the relevant part of my code". A real [mcve] I would estimate at a third of the length.

Comment: "expression must have arithmetic type" second line from the end.

Comment: Functions `quick_sort` and `input_array_dyn` are unknown. The definition `main()` is obsolete but backward-compatible.

Comment: Thanks for the additional info, but with "by adding a comment" I meant to [edit] the code in your question, adding a C-comment `/* error here */`. And while editing, take the opportunity to add the full and verbatim error message. Also, taking the [tour] would probably help you find your way at StackOverflow.

Comment: @WeatherVane It was my bad for not displaying the whole code, but  `size2` has been initialized in a function.

Comment: @Yunnosch Thank you, I'll be sure to have a look at it.

Comment: Yeah, I saw that and edited the previous comment. But it is good practice to initialise local variables to a manageable default value, especially when set by a function whose return value is not checked.

Comment: the posted code causes the compiler to output a long long string of warning messages.  When compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings.  ( for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11 )`   You could start with inserting the statement: `#include <assert.h>`  to expose the `assert()` function.

Comment: regarding: `int quick_sort(int *arr, int low, int high)`   This states that the function returns an `int`, however, the body of the function NEVER ever returns anything.  Suggest either rewriting the function -or- change the return type to `void`

Comment: when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions, always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: when calling any of the heap allocation functions: ( malloc, calloc, realloc ) 1) the return type is `void*` which can be assigned to any pointer.  Casting just clutters the code, making it more difficult to understand, debug, etc.  2) calling `assert()` to check for a failure of the function is not a good idea.,  much better to check (!=NULL) the returned value and if NULL, call `perror()` so a error message and the reason the system thinks the function failed are output to `stderr`

Comment: never trust the user.  even if that user is yourself.  so this statement: `scanf("%d", n);` (which allows a input of 0 or even <0 values should be followed by a check that the value input is >0

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) insert an appropriate space: inside parens, after commas, after semicolons, around C operators

Comment: variable names (and function parameters) should indicate `content` or `usage` (or better, both).  names like `SA`, `SB`, etc are meaningless, even in the current context.

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) consistently indent the code. Indent after every opening brace '{'. Unindent before every closing brace '}'. Suggest each indent level be 4 spaces. 2) separate code blocks ( 'for' if else while do...while switch case default ) via a single blank line. 3) separate functions by 2 or 3 blank lines (be consistent)   4) follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*

Comment: regarding this function: `int input_array_dyn(int*n)`  the body of the function returns a `int*`, not a `int`.   so the signature of the function should be: `int *input_array_dyn( int *n )`

Comment: regarding: `    int *arr3 = calloc(size2, sizeof(int)); arr3= find_intersection(arr1, arr2, arr3, size1, size2, &counter);`  results in a memory leak as the call to `find_intersection()` will overlay the pointer placed in `arr3` via the call to `calloc()`  and it fails to check if the call to `calloc()` was successful.

Comment: regarding: `int size1, size2, *counter, i=0;`   The variable `counter` is never set to point to any specific memory that the application owns, so it contains what ever trash is on the stack at its' location.  Strongly suggest modifying it to: `int size1, size2, counter, i=0;`

Comment: Notice: the parameter to `calloc()`, `malloc()` and `realloc()`  is a `size_t`, not a `int`.  While the `implicit conversion` feature of C will 'usually' save you, you should not depend on that feature.

Comment: when calling `realloc()`, always save the returned value into a temporary variable, so when the function fails, the original pointer is not lost.  Otherwise a memory leak will occur.  Also, `counter` is a pointer to a value. Suggest: `int *temp = realloc(arr3, (*counter)*sizeof(int));  if( !temp ) { perror( "realloc failed" );  // clean up then exit( EXIT_FAILURE ); }   // implied else, realloc successful  arr3 = temp;`

Comment: regarding: `a = calloc(*n, sizeof(double));`  the array `a[]` is an array of integers, so the statement should be: `a = calloc(*n, sizeof(int));`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `find_intersection()` `counter` is a pointer to an `int`. To change it's value you need to use `*counter` instead of `counter`.

Comment: So, I've changed all the  `counter` to `*counter` and it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`return arr3;` attempts to return a pointer to `int` while function is declared to return just `int`. `counter` is a pointer to an `int` while you are using it as an regular `int` setting to 0 and so on.